# Rxjava difference between flatMap just vs map return param

Tags: android, rx-java

Is there any difference between this:

```
public Observable<List<MessageDb>> getLastXMessages(int x, String userToGetMessagesFrom){
    return MainApplication.getInstance().getRiotXmppService().getRiotConnectionManager().getConnectedUser()
            .flatMap(connectedUser -> {
                QueryBuilder qb = 
        ... 
        ...         
                return Observable.just(qb.list());
            });
}
```

or this

```
public Observable<List<MessageDb>> getLastXMessages(int x, String userToGetMessagesFrom){
    return MainApplication.getInstance().getRiotXmppService().getRiotConnectionManager().getConnectedUser()
            .map(connectedUser -> {
                QueryBuilder qb = 
        ... 
        ...         
                return qb.list();
            });
}
```

Is there any preferable solution or both just works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure both work fine. If you are not planning to do stuff asynchronously then I'd prefer `map` because it carries less overhead than `flatMap`. Seeing as it looks like there are network calls involved in your example (?) that overhead would probably be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

FlatMap behaves very much like map, the difference is that it returns an observable itself, so its perfectly suited to map over asynchronous operations. Map does not have to emit items of the same type as the source Observable.

In the practical sense, Map just makes a transformation over the chained response (not returning an Observable); while FlatMap returns an Observable, that is why FlatMap is recommended if you plan to make an asynchronous call inside the method, So:

- Map returns an object of type T
- FlatMap returns an Observable.